# Heap that implements Comparable in Java

Tags: java

I have an array that is full of Doubles and I want to save those doubles in a heap.
The problem is I need to keep record of the index of the array.

```
Double[] array = new Double[n]; //imagine it's filled with doubles
```

Now I have a PriorityQueue:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> heap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(); //Integer because it's an heap of indexes
```

I want to add each element of the array to the heap, but I want to keep record of the INDEX. 
So imagine I add index 0 to the heap:

```
The heap stores 0, but uses array[0] to compare and sort it.
Not index 0 itself, that's just like a class index. Stores v but compares v.value
```

When I get a value from the heap:

```
Imagine I do heap.pull();
The heap returns me index 0, and then I will know the value is array[0].
```

Can I do this with comparable?

Comment: I'm wondering what you think "heap" means in this context. That term is usually used to refer to space used for memory allocation and garbage collection, not a priority queue. I also think this is an XY question -- you're asking us if a particular half-coded solution can be made to work, without telling us what problem you're trying to solve... and the answer may be that this is the wrong way to solve the problem, but we can't answer that with what you've given us. As it stands, I'd have to vote for "close as unclear".

Comment: Also, comparable is implemented on the objects you want to compare, not the container, so it may not be what you're looking for. And the answer may be to create a new class rather than working directly with Doubles and Integers.

Comment: The problem is explained correctly, heap does have a application in priorityqueue and what I wrote is an algorithm of what I want to do, so I can found a solution in Java.
Which I will now find it alone, and then write here so you can see my question is not unclear!!

Comment: Heap is indeed a data structure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question well. Try running the example below. See if you understand it and if this is the behaviour you are looking for.

```
int n = 10;
final double[] arr = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    arr[i] = Math.random() * 100;
}
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(n, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return (int) (arr[o1] - arr[o2]);
    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    queue.add(i);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(queue.toString());
```

Note this can result in an `OutOfBoundsException` very quickly when you add something unexpected to the `PriorityQueue`.